# Code not allowing letting me disable a script from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime-error, monodevelop

I'm having an issue where I can't disable a script from the other script - they are both public and within the same package (I think).

Here is my code for the script I'm trying to disable from:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
using RTS;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {

Canvas canvas;
private Player player;
public Button Button2;


void Start()
{
    Debug.Log ("asdf");
    player = transform.root.GetComponent< Player >();
    canvas = GetComponent<Canvas>();
    canvas.enabled = false;
    ResourceManager.MenuOpen = false;
    Button2.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { Resume();});
    if(player) player.GetComponent< UserInput >().enabled = false;
}
```

And the code for the other script:

```
//sets up what resources we are using
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using RTS;

public class UserInput : MonoBehaviour {

//sets up a private variable for only this class - our player
private Player player;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
//this goes to the root of the player ie the object player and allows us to
player = transform.root.GetComponent< Player > ();
}//end Start()
```

So the part that is not working is:

```
if(player) player.GetComponent< UserInput >().enabled = false;
```

And the code runs and then causes the runtime error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PauseMenu.Pause () (at Assets/Menu/PauseMenu.cs:40)
PauseMenu.Update () (at Assets/Menu/PauseMenu.cs:29)
```

Here is a picture showing my scene hierarchy and components:
[image: Scene hierarchy]

Comment: An alternative possibility to what Jorge suggests is that `player.GetComponent< UserInput >()` is returning `null`. In any case, try logging out the returned values from `GetComponent()` to narrow down the reason for your problem.

Comment: Thanks - it was the player bit going wrong as the userinput is part of the player object - i've posted a screenshot showing hierarchy but im not sure how to access the scripts within this object from my pausemenu

Comment: To clarify, which object in your scene contains the `PauseMenu` script as a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you try to execute `transform.root.GetComponent< Player >();` from within `PauseMenu`, which is on the "Canvas" object.

The problem with that is that the topmost `transform` in the hierarchy of your "Canvas" object (which is what [`transform.root`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-root.html) returns) is, well, the `transform` of the "Canvas" object - which is in no way related to the `UserInput` script you are trying to access. For this script to actually work, you would need the `transform` of your "Player" object, which is the object that actually has the `UserInput` script.

My suggestion is to eliminate the need to run `GetComponent()` at all - create a public `UserInput` variable in your `PauseMenu` class, then (while selecting your "Canvas") in the editor, drag the "Player" object into that new field. This will cause the `UserInput` script of your "Player" object to be accessible within the `PauseMenu`.

So your `PauseMenu` script might look like:

```
public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    Canvas canvas;
    public UserInput playerInput; // Drag the Player object into this field in the editor
    public Button Button2;

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log ("asdf");
        canvas = GetComponent<Canvas>();
        canvas.enabled = false;
        ResourceManager.MenuOpen = false;
        Button2.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { Resume();});
        playerInput.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

(An alternative is to use `GameObject.Find("Player")` to get `GameObject` of "Player". This needs a bit more code but doesn't use the editor.)

Comment: Great this works perfectly :) will there be any side effects with giving the pausemenu access to the player and having it as a public variable?

Comment: Glad I could help! I can't think of any problems that may arise, and it's the first way the [Unity manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html) suggests (see Accessing Other Objects). I've found it really useful, hopefully this opens a lot of doors for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your `player = transform.root.GetComponent< Player >();` arrives null. 
So you are trying to disable something that doesnt exist.
Enter debug mode and see if your `player` is null or not.

Comment: Thanks your right - it returns null - i realized it's because the script is not attached to the player but i don't want to do that - any way to access player from this script? I will attach a screenshot showing you the hierarchy and scripts for player (once i figure how :P)